# How can I backup and then restore SQL Server DBs to different names without overwriting existing DBs?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a small project to backup and restore databases to different name(s), and I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using SSMS v18.11.1 with SQL Server 2016, and I have seven databases, let's call them `DBCompanyA_1` ... `DBCompanyA_7`. Their `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are stored in the default location of

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

I want to make a full backup of each of those 7 databases (with logs) and then restore them to a different name. Using my example above, let's say that I want to restore them to `DBCompanyB_1` ... `DBCompanyB_7`.

The problem I keep encountering is that all attempts (using `MOVE`) overwrites the existing `DBCompanyA_n` databases, which is bad. I want to use backup and restore so that the DBs originals' permissions will carry over to the new DBs.

I don't care if the backup procedure is via UI or script, but the restore must be using T-SQL.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/62590/how-to-duplicate-mssql-database-on-the-same-or-another-server

Comment: https://documentation.commvault.com/v11/essential/87384_creating_instant_clone_for_sql_server.html

Comment: It seems you are specifying different file names with MOVE but not a new database name. Use T-SQL statement `RESTORE NewDatabasName FROM ... WITH MOVE ...`

Comment: "The problem I keep encountering is that all attempts (using MOVE) overwrites the existing DBCompanyA_n databases". Can you show your `RESTORE` statement? If it starts with `restore database DBCompanyA_n`, that explains why your database is getting overwritten.

Comment: My apologies -- I meant to paste the T-SQL I'm using.  (*duh*)  Here it is:

RESTORE DATABASE DBCompanyC_1
FROM DISK = 'C:\DBRestores\DBCompanyA_1' WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE 'DBCompanyA_1' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBCompanyC_1.mdf', MOVE 'DBCompanyA_1_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBCompanyC_1_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5;

I my case, the database named "DBCompanyA_1" will always exist on the target, I can't replace it, and I need to restore the backup of DBCompanyA_1 as DBCompanyC_1.